# Result is not stacking as desired via tuple or dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am grabbing some financial data off a website, a list of names and a list of numbers, respectively. However, if i print them independently, I get the results separately fine, but I can't manage to put them together.

```
import requests
import bs4
import numpy as np


def fundamentals(name, number):

    url = 'http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/dbfx_002230.html?date=2020-03-31#01c08'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) '
                      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36 QIHU 360SE'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'html5lib')
    DuPond_name = soup.find_all(name='td', attrs={'class': 'dbbg01'})
    DuPond_number = soup.find_all(name='td', attrs={'class': 'dbbg02'})
    for i, names in enumerate(DuPond_name, 1):
        name = names.getText()
        print(name)
    for i, numbers in enumerate(DuPond_number, 1):
        number = numbers.getText()
        print(number)
    return {name: number}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fundamentals(name=[], number=[]))
```

DOM

```
净资产收益率
总资产收益率
权益乘数
销售净利率
总资产周转率
净利润
营业收入
营业收入
平均资产总额
营业收入
全部成本
投资收益
所得税
其他
营业成本
销售费用
管理费用
财务费用
-1.16%
-0.63%
1/(1-40.26%)
-9.33%
0.07
-131,445,229.01
1,408,820,489.46
1,408,820,489.46
9,751,224,017.79
1,408,820,489.46
1,704,193,442.22
5,971,254
17,965,689
--
776,103,494
274,376,792.25
186,977,519.02
5,173,865.88
{'财务费用': '5,173,865.88'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

the final dict is only giving me the very last combination, how can i fix it? or if i can put them into dataframe form, sweeter. thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([list(DuPond_name), list(DuPond_number)]).T
```

For reference, This is how I tested it:

```
import pandas as pd

ls1 = ['净资产收益率','总资产收益率','权益乘数','销售净利率','总资产周转率','净利润','营业收入','营业收入','平均资产总额','营业收入','全部成本','投资收益','所得税','其他','营业成本','销售费用','管理费用','财务费用']

ls2 = ['-1.16%','-0.63%','1/(1-40.26%)','-9.33%','0.07','-131,445,229.01','1,408,820,489.46','1,408,820,489.46','9,751,224,017.79','1,408,820,489.46','1,704,193,442.22','5,971,254','17,965,689','--','776,103,494','274,376,792.25','186,977,519.02','5,173,865.88']

df = pd.DataFrame([ls1, ls2]).T

print(df)
```

This is the output I got:

```
  0                 1
0   净资产收益率            -1.16%
1   总资产收益率            -0.63%
2     权益乘数      1/(1-40.26%)
3    销售净利率            -9.33%
4   总资产周转率              0.07
5      净利润   -131,445,229.01
6     营业收入  1,408,820,489.46
7     营业收入  1,408,820,489.46
8   平均资产总额  9,751,224,017.79
9     营业收入  1,408,820,489.46
10    全部成本  1,704,193,442.22
11    投资收益         5,971,254
12     所得税        17,965,689
13      其他                --
14    营业成本       776,103,494
15    销售费用    274,376,792.25
16    管理费用    186,977,519.02
17    财务费用      5,173,865.88
```